# System of linear equations with a free variable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

The following matrix $A_n$ is an $(n-1) \times n$ matrix. I need to solve $A_nX = 0$, where $X = (x_1, \cdots, x_n)$.
\begin{equation}
A_n = \begin{bmatrix}
b_2 & a_2 & b_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b_3 & a_3 & b_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & b_4 & a_4 & b_5 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & b_5 & a_5 & b_6 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b_6 & a_6 & b_7 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & b_{n-1} & a_{n-1} & b_n\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & b_n & a_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Since
$$
-\dfrac{b_n}{a_n}x_{n-1} = x_n,
$$
so $x_n$ is a free variable and thus there is always a solution to this system of equations. Let us denote $x_m \sim x_j$ if we can write $x_j$ in terms of $x_m$. Therefore $x_{n-1} \sim x_n$.

By substituting $x_n$ by $x_{n-1}$ in $(n-1)$th row, it implies $x_{n-2} \sim x_{n-1}$ . Therefore we will end up with $x_1 \sim x_2$. My problem is to find the formula, say $\phi$, so that $x_2 = \phi x_1$. Now

> I need a hint to propose a method that can help to solve this problem.

Cramer's rule seems doesn't work because the right hand side is zero vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ingredients

- $AX=0$ is a **kernel issue**. As $A$ is $(n-1) \times n$, *assuming that $A$ has maximal rank $n-1$*, by rank-nullity theorem, this kernel is 1-dimensional. Therefore, it suffices to find a non-zero vector $V$ of this kernel ; the other elements will be $aV$ (with $a$ a free variable). How to do it ? By...
- **Block computation**. Consider decomposition $A=[U|B]$ where $U$ is the first column and $B$ a $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix. In the same way, decompose your column vector with unknowns $x_i$ into $\binom{x_1}{V}$ where $V=(x_2 \cdots x_n)^T$. In this way, system $AX=0$ becomes :

$$[U|B]\binom{x_1}{V}=0 \iff Ux_1+BV=0 \iff BV=-x_1U$$

which is a $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ system. Taking arbitrarily $x_1=1$ and solving the system (we assume that $B$ is "full-rank") will give a solution $V=V_s$. From this solution, you will get the basis of the kernel under the form :

$$\binom{x_1}{V_s}=\binom{1}{V_s}$$

Comment: I was dealing with your hint, I didn't come to a solution yet. Let me try more

Comment: I found the formula by substitution but can't prove it for general case :|

Comment: I meant I created some examples and found the formula. I also implemented the formula in Matlab and it is OK. But I can't prove it.

Comment: I have had a look at your well written (modified) question. I maintain that considering it as a kernel issue, you have the answer : find first a solution by taking an arbitrary values for $x_1$ ; then all other solutions are multiple of this one.

Comment: Your hint solved the problem. I studied computer science. I would like to complete and continue the paper in the field of Inverse Eigenvalue Problems that I am writing now with your cooperation. Are you willing to cooperate?

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=TUYba6sAAAAJ Is this your google scholar?